# Phone number login

Tags: android, ios, authentication, jwt, mobile-phones

I'm working on a mobile app available for both Android and iOS. We want to add users the ability to login only using their phone number, the same flow as the one used by WhatsApp (User inserts his number in some sort of screen -> Make request to our Server -> Server sends a verification code -> A new screen where the user puts in the code -> Validate the received code).

After the login I plan to send a JWT token or similar to be used for future requests, but in order to maintain security I want this token to expire after say a week for example. My question is, how can I re-authenticate the user after my token expires without the user noticing any changes?

I was thinking of using for re-authentication the device ID, the phone number used and the verification code. Would this be a good idea? Or what will be the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want re-authentication you need to inform user about it.
If you don't want noticing - you don't need re-authentication. Save phone number and use it when need:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:phoneString forKey:@"kProfilePhone"];
```

Comment: Theoretically they shouldn't be noticing it. The thing is that the client would get a token initially that is set to expire after a certain period, if you make a request after the token expired you should then have to request a new token right? My question was what would be the best way to request a new token, which would probably involve re-authenticating the user.

Comment: Simple way, check phone number, device ID and token after token expire, and replace oldToken with new one.